# Build Deluge on one Pi and then copy it over?

Tags: compiling, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This article [Installing Deluge 1.3.11 on a Raspberry Pi](http://www.onepitwopi.com/raspberry-pi/installing-deluge-1-3-6-on-a-raspberry-pi/) goes over how to build and compile Deluge on the same Pi that you want to run Deluge on.  What if I don't want all that new development software on my Pi?  Is there a way to build and compile on one machine, zip stuff up, and copy it to another?
In Windows there are installed programs and portable programs.  Would compiling on another machine build an installed program or a portable program?

Comment: Search for cross compiling. And don't use "deluge" as keyword.

Comment: Isn't cross compiling when you compile across architectures or OS's?  For example Windows -> Linux or vice versa.

Comment: No. Crosscompiling is about architectures, not OS.

Answer (score 2):

Compile a package or set of packages suitable for your distro (raspbian) rather than just do a `make install` into `/usr/local/` - the package(s) can then be copied and installed using the standard package management tool `dpkg` for raspbian.

This compilation could be done on your rpi itself with a suitable dev environment installed or it could be done on a faster, more powerful machine (another ARM box using the same kind of CPU - rare and unusual hardware) or cross-compiled on, e.g., an amd64 machine.